# Bluetooth device is not detected

Tags: usb, bluetooth

kubuntu version screenshot:

[image]

---

on my laptop, no Bluetooth device detected. I thought that maybe my laptop's internal Bluetooth device is broken so I bought a plug-use USB Bluetooth dongle but also it doesn't work.

On my linux, blueman-applet 2.1.2 installed.

maybe this output help you to help me:

> lsusb lsmod sudo rfkill list

```
ahmet@ahmet:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:5728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Lenovo EasyCamera
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 04b3:310d IBM Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
ahmet@ahmet:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 53248  0
hid                   110592  2 usbhid,hid_generic
ccm                    20480  3
devlink                45056  0
xt_CHECKSUM            16384  1
ipt_MASQUERADE         16384  3
nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4    16384  1 ipt_MASQUERADE
xt_conntrack           16384  1
ipt_REJECT             16384  2
nf_reject_ipv4         16384  1 ipt_REJECT
xt_tcpudp              16384  9
ip6table_mangle        16384  1
ip6table_nat           16384  1
nf_conntrack_ipv6      20480  1
nf_defrag_ipv6         20480  1 nf_conntrack_ipv6
nf_nat_ipv6            16384  1 ip6table_nat
iptable_mangle         16384  1
iptable_nat            16384  1
nf_conntrack_ipv4      16384  5
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_nat_ipv4            16384  1 iptable_nat
nf_nat                 32768  3 nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,nf_nat_ipv6,nf_nat_ipv4
nf_conntrack          131072  8 xt_conntrack,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv6,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_nat,nf_nat_ipv6,ipt_MASQUERADE,nf_nat_ipv4
libcrc32c              16384  2 nf_conntrack,nf_nat
nf_tables_bridge       16384  4
nf_tables              90112  1 nf_tables_bridge
nfnetlink              16384  1 nf_tables
ip6table_filter        16384  1
ip6_tables             28672  3 ip6table_filter,ip6table_nat,ip6table_mangle
iptable_filter         16384  1
bridge                155648  0
stp                    16384  1 bridge
llc                    16384  2 bridge,stp
xfrm_user              32768  2
xfrm_algo              16384  1 xfrm_user
binfmt_misc            20480  1
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
snd_hda_codec_conexant    24576  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_conexant
snd_hda_intel          45056  3
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
intel_rapl             20480  0
rtsx_usb_ms            20480  0
uvcvideo               86016  0
memstick               16384  1 rtsx_usb_ms
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
snd_pcm                98304  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
coretemp               16384  0
videobuf2_core         40960  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
kvm_intel             217088  0
btusb                  45056  0
videodev              184320  3 videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
media                  40960  2 videodev,uvcvideo
bluetooth             544768  6 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,btusb
kvm                   610304  1 kvm_intel
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
intel_cstate           20480  0
arc4                   16384  2
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
input_leds             16384  0
joydev                 24576  0
serio_raw              16384  0
iwldvm                229376  0
mac80211              786432  1 iwldvm
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
iwlwifi               290816  1 iwldvm
cfg80211              622592  3 iwldvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
ideapad_laptop         20480  0
snd                    81920  17 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
wmi                    24576  1 ideapad_laptop
mei_me                 40960  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mac_hid                16384  0
mei                    94208  1 mei_me
shpchp                 36864  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  10
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  3 iptable_filter,iptable_nat,iptable_mangle
x_tables               40960  11 ip6table_filter,xt_conntrack,iptable_filter,xt_tcpudp,ipt_MASQUERADE,xt_CHECKSUM,ip6_tables,ipt_REJECT,ip_tables,ip6table_mangle,iptable_mangle
autofs4                40960  2
rtsx_usb_sdmmc         28672  0
rtsx_usb               20480  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms
amdgpu               2715648  0
chash                  16384  1 amdgpu
i915                 1622016  31
radeon               1462272  2
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
pcbc                   16384  0
ttm                   106496  2 amdgpu,radeon
i2c_algo_bit           16384  3 amdgpu,radeon,i915
aesni_intel           188416  2
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
alx                    49152  0
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
drm_kms_helper        172032  3 amdgpu,radeon,i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ahci                   40960  2
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
psmouse               151552  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
i2c_i801               28672  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
drm                   401408  15 drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,radeon,i915,ttm
mdio                   16384  1 alx
video                  45056  2 ideapad_laptop,i915
ahmet@ahmet:~$ sudo rfkill list
[sudo] ahmet için parola: 
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
7: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
8: hci1: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
ahmet@ahmet:~$
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @David I added kubuntu version to question as editing

Comment: A simple line of text would have been better.

Comment: @David so do you know how to fix? kubuntu 20.04

Comment: You can search by `Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)`